# Magento 2 customer attribute not saved in database

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, eav-attributes

So I have created an attribute for customer entity, used it in frontend create account form, but it's not showing anything in `customer_entity_varchar` table, it's empty. However, in `eav_attribute` table I can see my attribute created.

Here is my code how I create the attribute.

InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Kage\RegisterForm\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributeCode = 'register_zip_code';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, 'register_zip_code', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Zip Code',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => '',
            'user_defined' => true,
            'is_user_defined' => false,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'position' => 1000,
            'default' => 0,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $registerZipCode= $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $registerZipCode->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $registerZipCode->getResource()->save($registerZipCode);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Template register.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field required regulation">
        <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Zip Code') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="register_zip_code" id="register_zip_code" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip Code') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

After I submit the form, It's not saved.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I found why, it's saved in customer_entity_text; not varchar lol , my mistake.